# How to print lines between pattern1 and 2nd match of pattern2?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Test file is given below:

```
PATTERN1
a
b
c
PATTERN2
d
e
f
PATTERN2
g
h
```

I want to print line between `PATTERN1` and 2nd match of `PATTERN2`:

```
PATTERN1
a
b
c
PATTERN2
d
e
f
PATTERN2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with `sed`:

```
sed '/PATTERN1/,$!d;/PATTERN2/{x;//{x;q;};g;}' infile
```

This just deletes all lines (if any) up to the first occurrence of `PATTERN1` and then, on each line that matches `PATTERN2` it e`x`changes buffers. If the new pattern space also matches, it means it's the 2nd occurrence so it e`x`changes back and `q`uits (after auto-printing). If it doesn't match it means it's the 1st occurrence so it copies the hold space content over the pattern space via `g` (so now there's a line matching `PATTERN2` in the hold buffer) and goes on...
and another way with `awk`:

```
awk '/PATTERN1/{t=1}; t==1{print; if (/PATTERN2/){c++}}; c==2{exit}' infile
```

It starts printing and counting lines matching `PATTERN2` only when encountering a line matching `PATTERN1` and exits when `c`ounter reaches `2`.

Comment: in my case PATTERN1 is a variable.  means xx=PATTERN1  so i want to use $xx instead of PATTERN1.  but the awk command is not working with it.  can you help me.  i tried  awk '/$xx/{t=1}; t==1{print; if (/PATTERN2/){c++}}; c==2{exit}' infile  but it is not working.

Comment: @sachin - `awk -v m="${xx}" '$0~m{t=1}; t==1{print; if (/PATTERN2/){c++}}; c==2{exit}' infile`

Comment: in another case, it should print data only if the PATTERN1 start the line. any solution ?

Comment: please provide solution to find the pattern at the start of line in the given command.     awk -v m="${xx}" '$0~m{t=1}; t==1{print; if (/PATTERN2/){c++}}; c==2{exit}' infile  .   because in my case the pattern 1 is a variable and coming in the start of line.

Comment: thanks for the reply, its working. can you please explain the whole command ?

Comment: @sachin - there's already an explanation in my answer above - the only difference is that this one uses a variable: `m` to read the regex from a shell variable `xx`. So instead of `/ PATTERN1/{t=1}` which means _if this line matches PATTERN1 then let t=1_ you have `$0~m{t=1}` which means _if this line matches `m` then let t=1_ and `m` is in this case `^PATTERN1` that is, line has to match `PATTERN1` at the beginning of line: `^`.  When that happens we set `t=1`. On each line we test if `t==1`, if so, we print. We count with `c` when a line matches `PATTERN2` and we exit when `c==2`.

Comment: @don_crissti Would it be possible to not print the last PATTERN2 and just exit for the `awk` solution?

Comment: @MarkusLindberg - yes, just switch the order of operations so as to exit before printing:  `awk '/PATTERN1/{t=1}; t==1{if (/PATTERN2/){c++}; if (c==2){exit}; print}' infile`

Answer (score 5):

The right tool for this job is `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -M 'PATTERN1(.|\n)*PATTERN2' file
```

where option `-M` allows pattern to  match more than one line and `(.|\n)*` match any character or newline zero or more times.

Notice that we took advantage of the greediness of the grep. If you would want to print form pattern1 up to the *first* occurrence of the pattern2, then non-greedy `*?` should be used instead of `*`.

As a generalization, to print up to the `n`th occurrence of PATTERN2:

```
pcregrep -M 'PATTERN1((.|\n)*?PATTERN2){n}' file
```

Change `n` to actual number you need.

Comment: As you are using multiline flag, so why not just `pcregrep -M 'PATTERN1.*PATTERN2' file`?

Comment: n my case PATTERN1 is a variable. means xx=PATTERN1 so i want to use $xx instead of PATTERN1. but the  command provided by you , is not working with it. can you help me. i tried pcregrep -M '$xx((.|\n)*?PATTERN2){2}' file infile but it is not working

Comment: @heemayl Because you have to provide both: `-M` and `\n`, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: @sachin Try `pcregrep -M "$xx"'((.|\n)*?PATTERN2){2}'  file`. The variable have to be inside double quotes, otherwise it is not expanded.

Answer (score 5):

Just use flags:

```
$ awk '/PATTERN1/{flag=2;next} flag; /PATTERN2/{flag--}' file
a
b
c
PATTERN2
d
e
f
PATTERN2
```

That is: when you find `PATTERN1` set the flag to a positive value; in particular, 2. Then, when you find `PATTERN2`, decrease that flag in one. This way, it will exhaust after the second match. In between, use `flag` as a value that triggers the `{print $0}` when it has a true value (2 or 1).

Comment: This will fail in any of the following circumstances: 1) if there's at least one line matching `PATTERN2` before the line matching `PATTERN1` (but not immediately before it) 2) if there are more than two lines matching `PATTERN2` after the line matching `PATTERN1` and the third line matching `PATTERN2` isn't the last line in the file or 3) if there's a second line matching `PATTERN1` in between the first two (of several) lines matching `PATTERN2` that follow the first line matching `PATTERN1`

Comment: Would it be possible to not print the last PATTERN2?

Comment: @MarkusLindberg you should either create some kind of buffering (otherwise, how do you know if it is the last PATTERN2?) or read the file backwards

Answer (score 2):

If we told regarding `sed` is to much easy to collect nesessary lines then print

```
sed -n '
    /PATTERN1/{
        :1
        $!N
        /\(PATTERN2\).*\1/!b1
        p
    }
' file
```